# confusion with results of `python setup.py install --user`

Tags: python, installation, setup.py

Say I have a python application that I want to install and if I run `python setup.py install --user`, everything gets put into `~/.local` as expected (on linux), and inside of that the stuff in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
gets seen by the PYTHONPATH as expected; however, my executables that are created by `setup.py` (using either `entry_points` via `setuptools` or `scripts` via `distutils`) are correctly put into `~/.local/bin`, but are not seen by the `PATH` at the command line.

Thus, I have to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to my `PATH` (via my `.zshrc`) to get these executables seen by my environment.  I'm assuming this is the expected behaviour, but my question is, is there some way to get my executables "registered" with my PATH when I run the installation with the `--user` flag during the setup?

I believe this should work, as I see that `ipython` does something like this, where if it's installed with the `--user` flag (into `~/.local`), then you don't have to add to your path `~/.local/bin` to get the local install of `ipython` seen at the command line. I just can't figure out how `ipython` does it. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using --user, why not use a virtualenv?  they are much more flexible, and put its bin directory on the path when activated.

Otherwise, manually putting ~/.local/bin on your PATH, as you did, is what you need to do.

Comment: I'm using `~/.local` for a somewhat complicated/specific use case where I cannot use a virtualenv (ie. executing remote commands via ssh across multiple compute cluster nodes where `~/.local` gets forwarded correctly, but virtualenv doesn't work correctly in my situation).  In any case, I just can't see how ipython puts itself on the system PATH, such that `~/.local/bin` doesn't need to be added to the environment PATH explicitly.

Comment: After some testing... it doesn't.  I uninstalled ipython from my system, confirmed its deletion with the unix find command, installed ipython via `python setup.py install --user` and it was NOT put in my path.  Also, after examining the source of the ipython install scripts, I see nothing that would override its script install location or modify the path.  If you have ipython installed outside of ~/.local, that script will run, and it will import its modules from ~/.local, since that would be higher in the python path.  Old command, new libraries.

Comment: Ah, got it, duh!  Thanks for checking this.  This was exactly what was happening -- I installed a local version of ipython (in `~/.local`), but didn't add `~/.local/bin` to my path; and when i called ipython, it must have been calling the server wide ipython executable in `/usr/bin`, which subsequently invoked/loaded my locally installed version b/c my local version was being referenced earlier in `sys.path`.  thanks for pointing out this oversight!